# Block not showing on page

Tags: 6, blocks, theming

I have a weird issue with a D6 site... A block I've created will not show up on the page. It appears to be disabled in the blocks list, although other blocks that /are/ showing up seem to be disabled as well. When I try to move it to a region, it jumps back to 'disabled' region.

Has anyone run into this issue and found a solution? Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Likely a different module is being used to control block display: Context or Panels would be the most likely options.  It's possible someone wrote a custom module to disable blocks in the standard blocks interface to force you away from it.

*Note: Drupal 6 is no longer officially supported by the community. While there are some places that are offering long term support for Drupal 6, you should plan to move to Drupal 7 or 8 soon.*